# To find the number of ways to choose such that none of them will be the same pair.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, recreational-mathematics

Suppose there are $10$ pairs of chocolates and each pair is distinct. To find the number of ways I can choose $5$ chocolates from $20$ such that none of them will be the same pair.

---

I tried the problem with the following argument:

Consider the pairs as blocks. So practically we choose $5$ chocolates from $10$ in $\binom{10}{5}$ ways. Since for each block, there are two identical chocolates we can choose it in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways. So the total number of ways is $$\binom{10}{5} \times \binom{2}{1}^5.$$

Is my argument correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it's correct. The other way to reach the same answer as you did is using Inclusion–exclusion principle. But your proof is straightforward.

Comment: Each pair is distinct but are the chocolates within each pair identical?

Comment: If both chocolates are identical within a pair, the answer should simply be $10 \choose 5$. If different, your answer seems correct.